# Addressing a*a mod m overflow problem where m is large

Tags: modular-arithmetic

is there another way to calculate a*a mod m mathematically? m is larger than a so (a%m)*(a%m) %m doesn't do anything, but a*a is large enough to overflow.

Comment: Which sizes are we talking about here? What kind of arithmetic do you have access to?

Comment: Anything doable in C++

Comment: I assume that you're already using `long` rather than `int` in your code? If so, then you should use the GMP bignum types for arbitrary precision arithmetic: http://gmplib.org/

Comment: I'm using int64's -- unfortunately I had a very difficult time getting GMP to work

Answer (score 2):

Break a down into base-b digits where (b-1)^2 is small enough that it does not overflow.  For example, use base-$2^{16}$ and 32-bit words or base $2^{32}$ and 64-bit words.  Then multiply these words by the usual algorithm (or, if you like, a faster algorithm like Karatsuba).

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest writing $a$ in base-$b$ digits, where $b$ is such $b*m$ doesn't overflow. You beat me to it with a variant of the same idea.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example, please?

Comment: Suppose you can only store numbers up to 3. You can solve 5 * 10 by writing the numbers in base 4 (11 times 22) and finding each of the cross-products: 1*2 shifted by 0, 1*2 shifted by 1, 1*2 shifted by 1, and 1*2 shifted by 2. That gives 2 + 20 + 20 + 200 (where the extra zeros denote the position of the digit -- you're not really storing more than just the 2s).  The last digit will be 2 since it's the only digit in that position. The next digit has a problem: 2+2 is too large and will overflow. So let the calculation wrap around: this should require doing nothing extra in C++ (which you

Comment: mention) but can be done as, for example, 2 - (4 - 2) = 0 with a carry. Now you have the carry of 1 plus the 2, which is small enough to carry out directly. So the final answer is 302 or 50 in base 10.